# URL redirect for certain posts to subdomain with htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm moving a blog to a subdomain for a fresh start, so I need the links to old posts to redirect from name.com to v1.name.com. But, there will be new posts at name.com that need to be ignored. I've changed the URL structure on the new blog installation so I can say only URLs with a month and year need redirected, but I haven't been able to get that working, and all the examples I've found are looking at changing the end of the URL, not the middle. What am I doing wrong with what's cobbled together below?

(And is there any way to achieve this without changing the URL structure on the new blog? I'd want all posts before /2013/12/ redirected, but I'm not aware of any way to specify that.)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^name.com/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2})/(.*)$  v1.name.com/$1/$2 [NC, R=301]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an old URL and it's corresponding new URL?

Comment: Additionally, what actually happens when you try your htaccess example? Do you get an error? Does the wrong page load?

Comment: I'd need name.com/2013/02/post-title/ to go to v1.name.com/2013/02/post-title/, and for any links that don't have a year and month to be ignored. Everything returns a 500 Internal Server Error right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you needed to move the hostname match into a separate condition, and add the `http://` bit in front of your substitution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} name.com
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2})/(.*)$  http://v1.name.com/$1/$2 [NC, R=301]
```

For bonus points, you said you wanted to match anything before 2013/12 - if I interpret that correctly to mean you want all posts from 2013 including December, you can do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} name.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(1[0-9]{3}|200[0-9]|201[0-3]) 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2})/(.*)$  http://v1.name.com/$1/$2 [NC, R=301]
```

And if you want to exclude December for 2013:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} name.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(1[0-9]{3}|200[0-9]|201[0-3]) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/2013/12 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2})/(.*)$  http://v1.name.com/$1/$2 [NC, R=301]
```

Comment: Holy crap, thank you! This helps a lot. I'm still getting the 500 error everywhere, even with just the first bit, but I feel a lot closer to figuring it out now.

Comment: OK, check your server error logs next. They should tell you the reason why you're getting a 500 Internal Server Error, so you can fix that first and then test the new htaccess code.

Comment: Whoops! The space in [NC, R=301] is what caused the error. It doesn't seem to be redirecting though, I'm just getting the standard page not found.

Comment: What's the final URL that you see in the address bar (when it says page not found)? And can you give a URL that does work on the subdomain?

Comment: The URL doesn't change at all when it says page not found. Wordpress has something going on in my htaccess as well, not sure if that's conflicting at all or something? I don't actually know what it does.

   `AddHandler php-stable .php
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule> `

Comment: Sorry, just tried taking that Wordpress code out and it worked!